# Python - arguments with white space

Tags: python, arguments

how can I please have argument with white space? I'm using script from

`http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm`

I'm creating a program for downloading subtitles from web. I have [-m[name of the movie]] argument with my script. The getopts from the site mentioned earlier does not count with white space opt argument.

For example: After -m The Mists I need to save "The Mists" into the variable. The problem is when I use the white space program end because of except expression in the code.

How can I please modify it to save the whole "The Mists" into the variable?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Pass the variable as "The Mists" from the command line?

Comment: This is likely to depend mostly on the operating system and the command shell you are using and not on python. I would also guess to use some kind of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function of the *shell* to parse out individual arguments for you; the majority of shells and consoles use quotes to delimit a single argument with spaces in it:

```
-m "The Mists"
```

Python is passed `'-m'` and `'The Mists'` as two separate arguments in such shells.